# How to convert list into different format using f{} and add string between them

Tags: python, list, printing

The list are below

```
second_list = ['C']
first_list =  ['A', 'B']
third_list  = ["D"]
```

Expected out is below

`the firstlist is A,B the second_list is C and thirdlist is D`

psudo code

```
print (f'the firstlist is {j for j in first_list } the second_list is {for j for j in second_list} and thirdlist is {for j for j in third_list')
```

Comment: aysh, it's not really good form to change your question in such a way that it invalidates all current answers, especially if it's been closed and can collect no *more* answers. Simply ask another question if that's your desire, there's no real limit. Have rolled it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `join`

```
second_list = ['C']
first_list =  ['A', 'B']
third_list  = ["D"]
print (f'the firstlist is {",".join(first_list)} the second_list is {",".join(second_list)} and thirdlist is {",".join(third_list)}')
```

```
the firstlist is A,B the second_list is C and thirdlist is D
```

Answer (score 1):

Your pseudo-code is *very* close but you're better off using `string.join` to create the comma-separated lists (the expressions in f-strings can be arbitrarily complex):

```
second_list = ['C']
first_list =  ['A', 'B']
third_list  = ["D"]

print (f'the firstlist is {",".join(first_list)} the second_list is {",".join(second_list)} and thirdlist is {",".join(third_list)}')
```

Output:

```
the firstlist is A,B the second_list is C and thirdlist is D
```